# NCMBで、条件を指定して件数のカウントをしたい

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

NCMB(NIFTY Cloud mobile backend)のデータストアから、
条件を指定して件数を取得したいのですが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか。

具体的な例を以下に記載します。

```
name | date
-------------
  A  |  6/1
  A  |  6/2
  A  |  7/1
  B  |  6/1
```

上記のようなクラスがあった場合に、
[name] 毎に [date] が【6/1 ～ 6/30】のデータを、
カウントするようなクエリを作ることは可能でしょうか。

```
A:2件
B:1件
```

Monaca,OnsenUI v2,AngularJS v1 の環境で開発しております。
ご教授のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL`の`GROUP BY`のような機能はないので、自分でカウントするしかないと思います。

```
test.greaterThanOrEqualTo("date", "0601")
    .lessThanOrEqualTo("date", "0630")
    .fetchAll()
    .then(function(result) {
        var count = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (count.hasOwnProperty(result[i].name)) {
                count[result[i].name] += 1;
            } else {
                count[result[i].name] = 1;
            }
        }
        console.log(count["A"]);
        console.log(count["B"]);
    });
```

Comment: ご返事大変遅くなりました。本日試してみたところ、問題なく動きました！ありがとうございます。